# Parse JSON from API URL using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to display JSON from API url using ajax and 'GET' method.

```
function getLatestComments() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://***********-API.amazonaws.com/deploymentstage/ride',
            headers: {
                Authorization: authToken
            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                var text = $("body").append(JSON.stringify(data.records));
                console.log(text);
                text.forEach(function(records) {
                $('#messages').append ('<p> +comments + </p>')
                    
                });
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.error('Something went wrong: ', err);
            }
        });
    }
```

JSON from URL :

```
statusCode  200
records 
0   "\"Lets give it a try\""
1   "\"this time its west\""
2   "\"Abcdef\""
3   "\"this is another test\""

headers 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: Let me post the function I am trying one more time..

Comment: `contentType` is not necessary in `GET` requests, since you're not sending any contents.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Looks like your data is there so  it might just be the space in your append method.

Comment: What is `comments`?

Comment: `text.forEach()` doesn't make much sense. You're looping over the elements of `$("body")`, not records from the JSON.

Comment: it is displayed on my html page like this:

Comment: ["\"sdfdsfdsfds\"","\"this time its west\"","\"sdsdsad\"","\"this is another test\"","\"test123\"","\"test2\"","\"test123\"","\"test123\"","\"love this event\""]

Comment: What you probably want is `data.records.forEach(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looping over the JSON array properly. `text` contains the jQuery object `$("body")`, not anything from the JSON response.

You want

```
data.records.forEach(comment => $('#messages').append ('<p>' +comment + '</p>'));
```